# Getting File from form field in Django

Tags: python, django, file, input

Similar to this question:

[How to get value from form field in django framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706255/)

Except the "value" field is a file. Is there a way to grab it directly? I called .value() on the field but it does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FileField's](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#filefield) are objects.

To access the file, simply call:

```
<file_field_instance>.file
```