# How can I Convert TypedChoiceField to Int in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to convert the data from a choicefield into an INT, but gets the error:

"int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'TypedChoiceField'"

However, I don't understand why the coerce=int, doesn't convert the data from the choicefield into an int.

My forms.py class

```
class ReviewForm(forms.Form):
readability_rating = forms.TypedChoiceField(
    choices=[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)], coerce=int)
```

My views.py function

```
def readerpage(request, content_id):
   form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
   if form.is_valid():
        review.readability_rating = forms.TypedChoiceField(
                        choices=[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)], coerce=int)
        review.save()
        form = ReviewForm()
        return redirect('home')
```

My model

```
class Review(models.Model):
   readability_rating = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

Thanks for reading this

Answer (score 0):

This assignment is a mistake, this is not how forms work:

```
if form.is_valid():
    review.readability_rating = forms.TypedChoiceField(
                        choices=[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)], coerce=int)
```

Please, go through [forms tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/).

And also check this answer: [How to get value from form field in django framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706255/how-to-get-value-from-form-field-in-django-framework))

If you seek good understanding of how Django works, I would also recommend a Book: Apress Pro Django.

I hope it'll help.

Comment: Oh... then my answer is completely irrelevant.