# CharField on django is outputted as (<django.forms.fields.CharField object at XXXX>,)

Tags: python, django

I'd like to output the input field on the template, but it is outputted as

> django.forms.fields.CharField object at XXXX

[image: error messages]

How can I fix this issue? I have tried many ways to fix it. But I could not solve the issues.

#### source codes occur the error

```py
views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from . import forms


def index(request):
    form = forms.Page1(request.GET or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        message = 'データ検証に成功しました'
    else:
        message = 'データ検証に失敗しました'
    content = {
        'title': 'とあるウェブアプリ',
        'form': form,
        'message': message,
    }
    return render(request, 'forms.html', content)
```

```py
forms.py

from django import forms

EMPTY_CHOICES = (
    ('', '-'*10),
)

GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('man', '男'),
    ('woman', '女')
)


class Page1(forms.Form):
    user_sir_name = forms.CharField(
        label='姓',
        max_length=20,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(),
    ),
    user_given_name = forms.CharField(
        label='名',
        max_length=20,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(),
    ),
    user_sex = forms.ChoiceField(
        label='性別',
        widget=forms.Select,
        choices=EMPTY_CHOICES + GENDER_CHOICES,
        required=True,
    )
```

```html
forms.html

{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  {{ message }}
  <hr>
  <form method="get" action="">
    {{ form.errors.user_sir_name }}
    <label>{{ form.user_sir_name.label }} {{ form.user_sir_name }}</label><br>

    {{ form.errors.user_given_name }}
    <label>{{ form.user_given_name.label }} {{ form.user_given_name }}</label><br>


    {{ form.errors.user_sex }}
    <label>{{ form.user_sex.label }} {{ form.user_sex }}</label><br>

    <br>

    <input type="submit" value="送信">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="ja">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

    <!-- semantic.css  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.3/semantic.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'page1/css/style.css' %}">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.9/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <!-- semantic.js  -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.3/semantic.min.js"></script>



    <title>とあるウェブアプリ</title>
<style>


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui inverted large borderless fixed fluid menu column">
    <a href="/" class="header item"><h1>{{title}}</h1></a>
</div>
<--You can edit contents below: -->
 <div class="ui container" style="min-height:100vh;margin-top: 200px">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>

<div class="ui inverted stackable footer segment">
    <div class="ui container center aligned">
        <div class="ui horizontal inverted small divided link list">
            <a class="item">© 2019 とあるウェブアプリ</a>
            <a class="item">利用規約</a>
            <a class="item">プライバシーポリシー</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### version info

Windows10,Python 3.7.5,Django(3, 0, 2, 'final', 0)

Answer (score 2):

Problem in comas after fields in you models, just remove it.

all code like `a = 1,` python means as `a = (1,)`

Comment: class Page1(forms.Form):
    user_sir_name = forms.CharField(
        label='姓',
        max_length=20,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(),
    )
    user_given_name = forms.CharField(
        label='名',
        max_length=20,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(),
    )
    user_sex = forms.ChoiceField(
        label='性別',
        widget=forms.Select,
        choices=EMPTY_CHOICES + GENDER_CHOICES,
        required=True,
    )

Answer (score 0):

just remove the (,) from forms.py file there is no need to give , between  two fields

forms.py

```
class Page1(forms.Form):
    user_sir_name = forms.CharField(
        label='姓',
        max_length=20,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(),
    )
    user_given_name = forms.CharField(
        label='名',
        max_length=20,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(),
    )
    user_sex = forms.ChoiceField(
        label='性別',
        widget=forms.Select,
        choices=EMPTY_CHOICES + GENDER_CHOICES,
        required=True,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706255/how-to-get-value-from-form-field-in-django-framework) helpful, simply use `.cleaned_data`

Ex: `form.cleaned_data['my_form_field_name']`