# How to return value to view after select item from dropdown list in django

Tags: django

i have a dropdown list  having the store name,when i select a store from that i need store_key from that select value

```
def store_list(request):
     displaystores=stores.objects.all()
     if request.POST:
         store_pk_list = request.POST.getlist('stores', None)
         print(request.POST.getlist('stores.unit_key', None))

         selected_store_obj_list = stores.objects.filter(pk__in=store_pk_list)
         print(selected_store_obj_list)
        
    return render(request,'storelist.html',{'stores':displaystores})
```

html

```
 <form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
```

--store_name--

```
 {%for result in stores%}
  <option value="{{result.unit_key}}">{{result.unit_name}}</option>
  {%endfor%}

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the form through the POST, validate the data and then use them,
Check this,

[getting value from form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706255/how-to-get-value-from-form-field-in-django-framework/31385897)